# How to type and read the symbol '||-'

Tags: logic

I've met the symbol `||-` many times in modal logic textbooks, especially in epistemic logic books. But I cannot find any info about how to type or read it. Usually, it means "**semantical entailment**" or "**modelling**" in modal logic.

But in first-order logic, semantical entailment is symbolised as `|=`. By contrast, we also use `|-` to express "**syntactical entailment**" or "**proving**".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Wecome to the TeX.SE. `\Vdash` it is the symbol.

Comment: According to Unicode, the character ⊩ is U+22A9 FORCES

Comment: Asking how to obtain the symbol is on-topic (but duplicate); asking how you read the symbol isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you searching for this symbol?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$A\Vdash B$
\end{document}
```

[image]